# Text not aligned and trimmed

Tags: bug, status-declined, mobile-web, safari

Many times I have seen "Interesting" text trimmed at the bottom, and  not aligned with "show".

#### iOS 10.3.1

[image]

#### Android Version 5.0.2 with Chrome Browser version 55.0.2883.91

[image]

#### iOS version - 7.1.2

[image]

Comment: Only current versions of mobile browsers are supported; the Safari version on [iOS versions that still support iPhone 4](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/174061/what-is-the-latest-ios-version-for-iphone-4) are too old, I fear. See [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161)

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters for quick reverts. I always like stackoverflow and actively participating. I though it should be highlight to resolve design related issue. Thanks again.

Comment: Absolutely! However, unless this is something that can be reproduced on a recent version of Mobile Safari, it's not something the SO devs would look at. Sorry!

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think devs must have to look at this thing as I am also facing same issue in Android Version 5.0.2 with Chrome Browser version 55.0.2883.91.

Comment: @vivek: I think the meta post is outdated for Android support; the data is from 2014. Looking at the [Android version history]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history) I'd expect versions 6 and 7 to be supported, but it'll take a Stack Overflow dev to confirm or deny. I'll ping a community manager to take a look.

Comment: And for the record: I can't reproduce this on my iOS 10 device, on either Safari or Chrome.

Comment: @MartijnPieters sure...but just for your information this screenshot is of stackoverflow not of the meta post.

Comment: @vivek: I know, the screenshot has the URL in the top. :-) It's the one I checked.

Comment: I guess @vivek wants to give stackoverflow.com screen shot from his Android device.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I thought you didn't noticed thats why you told that meta post is outdated for Android Support.